# Apple Pay - Processing Payments

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, payment-processing, applepay, applepayjs

The company I work for - a **Payment Service Provider** (EU based) has requested (and received) access to the Apple Pay API and **plan to process payments through our solutions for Web and Mobile Checkouts**.

Our goal is to add Apple Pay as an option in the checkout solutions that are used by our clients/merchants.
We will also be **handling the payment processing ourselves**.
We noticed that in the Apple Pay Platform Web Merchant Terms and Conditions on point 5.2 Platform providers it states that:
“If You are a Platform Provider, You may provide Platform Provider Services **only if permitted by Apple** and pursuant to the terms and conditions of the Platform Provider Addendum”
In regards to this, are there any additional steps which need to be taken by us, in order for Apple to approve our request to process Apple Pay payments?

We also wanted to know **if we will have any charges** in our role as a Payment Service Provider / Payment Processor?

We tried sending emails through every contact form that we found on the Apple website and called support, but no one was able to answer any of our questions or even point us in the right direction as to where to get them.

Any information on the matter would be greatly appreciated!

Kind regards,
Viktor